# Deserialize with LINQ query code in PageModel or PageView

Tags: c#, comparative-review, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Today I do something like this, where I get, select and sort some data and pass it on to the view (which loads a partial view) as a list of custom objects

Page model

```
public PagesSettings PageSettings { get; set; }
public List<Reportage> itemListReportages { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    PageSettings = (PagesSettings)HttpContext.Items["pagesettings"];

    if (PageSettings == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var fileContent = _fileService.GetFileContentCached(PageSettings.DataFile);

    if (fileContent?.Length > 0)
    {
        itemListReportages = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reportage>>(fileContent))
            .Where(l => l.Published)
            .OrderBy(l => l.Name)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Page view

```
@page
@model ListReportagesModel

@if (Model.PageSettings?.Data?.Count > 1 && Model.PageSettings.Data[1].Html?.Length > 0)
{
    <section class="content @(Model.PageSettings.SectionClass ?? "")">
        <div>
            @if (Model.PageSettings.Data[1].Values?.Length > 0)
                {
                    @Html.Raw(String.Format(Model.PageSettings.Data[1].Html, Model.PageSettings.Data[1].Values))
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.Raw(@Model.PageSettings.Data[1].Html)
                }
        </div>
    </section>
}

<section class="content @(Model.PageSettings.SectionClass ?? "")">
    <div class="aflex aflexwrap aflexspacebetween">
        <partial name="/Pages/Partial/@Model.PageSettings.PartialView" />
    </div>
</section>
```

Partial view

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.itemListReportages.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itembkg" style="background-image: url('@Model.itemListReportages[i].BkgImage');"></div>
        <div class="itemtxt">
            <span>@Model.itemListReportages[i].Text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

---

It now start to become a lot of `PageModel`'s, so I started to wonder where the proper location to run C# code is. In above the data loading/select/sort is done in the `PageModel` and the rest in the view's.

I was planning to split it up like below instead, moving the select/sort from `Pagemodel` to the partial view, and with that reduce the amount of `Pagemodel`'s and make it simpler to add data by simply create a new class + data file + partial view.

The question, which way is recommended (if any), perform *select/sort* in `PageModel` or in `View`?

Page model

```
public PagesSettings PageSettings { get; set; }
public string fileContent { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    PageSettings = (PagesSettings)HttpContext.Items["pagesettings"];

    if (PageSettings == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    fileContent = _fileService.GetFileContentCached(PageSettings.DataFile);
}
```

Partial view

```
if (fileContent?.Length > 0)
{
    var itemListReportages = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reportage>>(fileContent))
        .Where(l => l.Published)
        .OrderBy(l => l.Name)
        .ToList();

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.itemListReportages.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="item">
            <div class="itembkg" style="background-image: url('@Model.itemListReportages[i].BkgImage');"></div>
            <div class="itemtxt">
                <span>@Model.itemListReportages[i].Text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to rollback your last edit as it is not allowed to modify the code after reviews have been posted. It could (and in this case it did) invalidate them.

Comment: This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: When you do this, then I'll vote to close your qustion for posting hyphotetical code as this is off-topic on Code Review. I'll also delete my answer. Let's preted this has never happened ;-P and next time, please just copy/paste all of your code without changing it.

Comment: @t3chb0t -- Are you saying that I should have posted 1200 lines of code + all the linked/used utility library methods, and then ask about 20 lines of them (the one I posted), which is the main logic of my question?

Comment: Nope, I mean that the posted code should be complete. Not your entire application but a method... a class, a (partial)view etc. Otherwise this is the result... you get a review and you replay _but I already do this_... it simply backfires and isn't helpful to anyone, especially to you.

Comment: @t3chb0t -- Well, the _but I already do this_ were about a very minor thing in my case, a null check, which has nothing to do with what I actually asked. I assume you review _all_ the code, not the logic of it, which I asked for. Maybe I should have posted at Software Engineering instead...?

Comment: You posted it in the right place. Yes, CR reviews can be about anything. You're saying you are interested primarily in reviews about the logic and yet you remove crucial parts of it. Software Engineering will send you back to us when you show them the code. If you really want only logic reviews then make sure you describe it clearly. Code is rarely necessary for it. They accept also pseudocode, we don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find you should keep the library code in the model and only parts that are relevant to views inside them.

---

In your case there is actually a third option. Let `OnGet` only handle the file. Remove `OrderBy` as this is a view's matter how it's displayed. Additionally initialize `itemListReportages` to an empty list if a file was empty. It'll save you the trouble of `null` checks later.

```
public void OnGet()
{
    PageSettings = (PagesSettings)HttpContext.Items["pagesettings"];

    if (PageSettings == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var fileContent = _fileService.GetFileContentCached(PageSettings.DataFile);

    itemListReportages = 
        fileContent?.Length > 0
            ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reportage>>(fileContent).Where(l => l.Published).ToList()
            : new List<Reportage>();
}
```

We don't see whether you initialize `itemListReportages` but this view could crash because you don't use the null propagation operator here: `?.Count`

> ```
> @for (var i = 0; i < Model.itemListReportages.Count; i++)
> {
>     <div class="item">
>         <div class="itembkg" style="background-image: url('@Model.itemListReportages[i].BkgImage');"></div>
>         <div class="itemtxt">
>             <span>@Model.itemListReportages[i].Text</span>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> }
> ```

With a non-null list you can turn this into a `foreach` loop and put `OrderBy` here. It'll make the code shorter too as you now have an `item` variable and no longer have to acces them by index like `Model.itemListReportages[i]`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.itemListReportages.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itembkg" style="background-image: url('@item.BkgImage');"></div>
        <div class="itemtxt">
            <span>@item.Text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: @dfhwze how do you even spot these whitespaces? haha

Comment: That's what I do o_O I spot zombies and white space :p

Comment: For the record, I do check for _null propagation operator `?.Count`_, though simply missed that, and thanks for your answer.